# What are the specific save import bonuses for Mass Effect 3

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 2, importing a ME1 save would grant starting bonuses based on your level and the completion of certain achievements.

For example:

- A portion of the character's Paragon/Renegade points (up to 190 each,
  which requires the bar(s) to be 50% full[1]) are transferred over.
- Importing a level 1 through level 49 character will grant 1,000 XP
  (the player starts at level 2), 20,000 credits, and 2,500 of each
  resource.
- Importing a level 50 through level 59 character will grant 2,000 XP
  (the player starts at level 3), 30,000 credits, and 5,000 of each
  resource.
- Importing a level 60 character will grant 4,000 XP (the player starts
  at level 5), 50,000 credits, and 10,000 of each resource.
- Having the "Rich" achievement from Mass Effect will grant an
  additional 100,000 credits. The import bonuses will stack with the
  Mass Effect 2 completion starting bonuses (200,000 credits and 50,000
  of each resource).

My question is in the title. Are there any similar import bonuses for ME3, if so what are they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shepard **retains** his level, as opposed to starting from level 1.

Some amount of your earned Paragon/Renegade/Reputation Points transfers, but I don't have a formula for this.

Additionally, some imported decisions can affect the Readiness Level in the Galaxy at War section of the game.  I.E., having some amount of resources mined is worth 25 points of readiness.

Comment: So there are no monetary perks?

Comment: Your credits reset to zero at the beginning of ME3.

Comment: I'm still finishing ME2 right now (almost done!), but I have to say that it will make it easier on me now knowing that I won't have any perks for ending with a fat wallet.